# Avoid HTTP Request being marked as failed if 1 embedded ressource is not found

Tags: jmeter

When asking the HTTP samplers to download embedded resources it will fail the  entire request if any of the embedded resources fetching has failed (for  example a CSS which doesn't exists).

I would like to have an option to ignore such errors. For example, I would like  to use JMeter to generate a load which tests a switch I wrote - but if it fails  for embedded resources I can't tell if the reason to the error was my switch or something else (a 404 errors on embedded resources are very common).

I would  like to be able to run a full success scenario using JMeter w/o my switch, then  to plug-in the switch and see the difference."

How to fix it, as feature is developed within this bug:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you’re looking for.
Add this in user.properties file and restart JMeter:

> httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true

If embedded resources download fails due to missing resources or other reasons, if this property is true, Parent sample will not be marked as failed.

Comment: Please tell me where I need to to mention this line of code "httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true" in which file of jmeter at which position?

Comment: can you please add an attachment where you are inserting the this line of code as user properties has 3 main section and I do not want to touch it without knowing to put this line of code to exact position. thank you so much for helping me in this regard.

Comment: Just add it at end of file after adding a new empty line following the last line

Comment: please see my edit question where I put the image on link "enter image description here" and suggest me.. I really appreciate your patience and help to this newly jmeter  user. :)

Comment: Remove the "#" before the value as in my answer. If answer is ok, please accept it so that it helps others

Comment: you Rock man you Rock.. by removing # my parent sample is pass now, whatever css is unable to find.